# Узнать message_id в Telegram API

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Бот отправляет сообщение через bot.send_message() и потом для его изменения нужен chat_id и message_id. С chat_id проблем нет, но не могу понять где и как взять message_id отправленного ботом сообщения

Comment: Согласно документации телеграма sendMessage возвращает всю необходимую информацию о сообщении. А о каком таком bot.send_message() речь в вашем случае, непонятно

Comment: боту приходит json, в нем есть chat, в нем id. если коротко

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
message.message_id
```

Должно сработать